# onclick pop up divs but only 1 works at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 onclick div popups that work ok but I have 2 issues with them

1. Only one will close if you click outside of the div.
2. When one is open and you click another one that one stays open and will not close.

I am a new coder and know very little about javascript. I would be extremely grateful if someone could please help me with this. It is basically the last thing I need to figure out for my website.

Thank you for and and all help you can give me with my 2 problems. Have a great day.

```js
document.getElementById("myPopup").addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
        }); 
        function myFunction(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function onBodyClick(event) {
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "myPopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunction(event);
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Bell     
document.getElementById("mypopup").addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
        }); 
        function myFunctions(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function onBodyClick(event) {
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "mypopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunctions(event);
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Heart
document.getElementById("mYpopup").addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
        }); 
        function myFunctionss(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function onBodyClick(event) {
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "mYpopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunctionss(event);
  }
}   
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Menu 
document.getElementById("mYpopuP").addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
        });     
function myFunctionsss(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopuP");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function onBodyClick(event) {
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "mYpopuP") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopuP");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunctionsss(event);
  }
}
```

```css
/******************************************************************************************************************************************************Header*/
.s-header {
background-color: transparent; 
bottom: 0;
height: 65px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.s-header-inner {
background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid transparent;
height: 63px;
margin: auto;
width: 95%;
}

.s-header-links-left {
float: left;
margin-top: 12px;
}   

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************Logo*/
.s-logo { 
height: 65px;
position: absolute; 
width: 150px;    
}

.s-logo img {
position: absolute;     
width: 185px;
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************************************Amount Raised*/
.s-header-links-right {
border: 1px solid transparent;
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.tooltip { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.amount {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
}

.amount:hover {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
}

#myPopup { 
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -190px;
margin-top: 8px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 205px;
z-index: 1;
}

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************Bell*/
.bell {
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
}

.fa-bell {
color: red;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.fa-bell:hover {
color: red;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.tooltips { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mypopup {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -271px;
margin-top: 7px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
width: 345px;
z-index: 1;
}

#mypopup a {
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;   
text-decoration: underline;
}

#mypopup a:hover {
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;   
text-decoration: underline;
}

strong {
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;   
}

/*******************************************************************************************************************************************************Heart*/
.heart {
cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-heart {
color: red!important;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.fa-heart:hover {
color: red!important;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.toolstip { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mYpopup {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -298px;
margin-top: 7px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 325px;
z-index: 1;
}

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************Menu*/
i.fa-ellipsis-v {
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

i.fa-ellipsis-v:hover {
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

.menu {
cursor: pointer;
}

.toolstips { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mYpopuP {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: 7px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 150px;
z-index: 1;
}

.toolstips { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mYpopuP a {
color: #ffffff; 
display: block;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#mYpopuP a:hover {
color: #ffffff; 
display: block;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

/******************************************************************************************************************************************************Middle*/
.middle {
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 0px;
bottom: 0;
height: 275px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 525px;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="onBodyClick(event)"
<div class="s-header">
<div class="s-header-inner">
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Logo -->
<div class="s-header-links-left">
<div class="s-logo">
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/" target="_top">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/images/cape-breton-cares-logo-1.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Header Links Right -->
<div class="s-header-links-right">
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Amount Raised -->
<span class="tooltip" onclick="myFunction(event)">
<div class="amount">$234.41</div>
<span id="myPopup" style="display: none;">This is how much money our community has raised to help provide meals and support to animal charities in our local communities.
</span></span>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Bell -->
<span class="tooltips" onclick="myFunctions(event)">
<div class="bell">
<i class='far fa-bell'></i>
</div>
<span id="mypopup" style="display: none;">
<strong>Cape Breton Cares' Brand New Look!</strong>
<br/>
<br/>
We urge you to please share Cape Breton Cares with your friends and family to help provide more meals and support for animal organizations in our local communities.
<p><a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/spread-the-word/" target="_blank">Spread The Word</a></p>
Stay tuned for exciting updates coming soon.
</span>
</span>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Heart -->
<span class="toolstip" onclick="myFunctionss(event)">
<div class="heart">
<i class="far fa-heart"></i>
</div>
<span id="mYpopup" style="display: none;">
Every New Tab you open helps provide meals and support for animal organizations in our local communities. On average we need around 100 New Tabs to provide $1 of support to help our local animal organizations!
</span>
</span>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Menu -->
<span class="toolstips" onclick="myFunctionsss(event)">
<div class="menu">
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<span id="mYpopuP" style="display: none;">
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/contact/" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/donations/" target="_blank">Our Donations</a>
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/privacy-policy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/terms-of-use/" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>
</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function onBodyClick(event) {
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "mYpopuP") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopuP");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunctionsss(event);
  }
  
  
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "myPopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunction(event);
  }
  
   var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "mypopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunctions(null);
  }
  
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "mYpopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
   var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunctionss(event);
  }
}


document.getElementById("myPopup").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

function myFunction(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Bell
document.getElementById("mypopup").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
function myFunctions(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Heart
document.getElementById("mYpopup").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
function myFunctionss(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Menu
document.getElementById("mYpopuP").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
function myFunctionsss(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopuP");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  console.log(popup.style.display);
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
/******************************************************************************************************************************************************Header*/
.s-header {
background-color: transparent; 
bottom: 0;
height: 65px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.s-header-inner {
background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid transparent;
height: 63px;
margin: auto;
width: 95%;
}

.s-header-links-left {
float: left;
margin-top: 12px;
}   

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************Logo*/
.s-logo { 
height: 65px;
position: absolute; 
width: 150px;    
}

.s-logo img {
position: absolute;     
width: 185px;
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************************************Amount Raised*/
.s-header-links-right {
border: 1px solid transparent;
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.tooltip { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.amount {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
}

.amount:hover {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
}

#myPopup { 
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -190px;
margin-top: 8px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 205px;
z-index: 1;
}

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************Bell*/
.bell {
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
}

.fa-bell {
color: red;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.fa-bell:hover {
color: red;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.tooltips { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mypopup {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -271px;
margin-top: 7px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
width: 345px;
z-index: 1;
}

#mypopup a {
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;   
text-decoration: underline;
}

#mypopup a:hover {
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;   
text-decoration: underline;
}

strong {
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;   
}

/*******************************************************************************************************************************************************Heart*/
.heart {
cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-heart {
color: red!important;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.fa-heart:hover {
color: red!important;
font-size: 20px!important;
}

.toolstip { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mYpopup {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -298px;
margin-top: 7px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 325px;
z-index: 1;
}

/********************************************************************************************************************************************************Menu*/
i.fa-ellipsis-v {
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

i.fa-ellipsis-v:hover {
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

.menu {
cursor: pointer;
}

.toolstips { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mYpopuP {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
border-radius: 5px;
border-top: 4px solid #da291c;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: 7px;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px ;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 150px;
z-index: 1;
}

.toolstips { 
display: inline-block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

#mYpopuP a {
color: #ffffff; 
display: block;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#mYpopuP a:hover {
color: #ffffff; 
display: block;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

/******************************************************************************************************************************************************Middle*/
.middle {
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 0px;
bottom: 0;
height: 275px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 525px;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="onBodyClick(event)"
<div class="s-header">
<div class="s-header-inner">
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Logo -->
<div class="s-header-links-left">
<div class="s-logo">
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/" target="_top">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/images/cape-breton-cares-logo-1.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Header Links Right -->
<div class="s-header-links-right">
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Amount Raised -->
<span class="tooltip" onclick="myFunction(event)">
<div class="amount">$234.41</div>
<span id="myPopup" style="display: none;">This is how much money our community has raised to help provide meals and support to animal charities in our local communities.
</span></span>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Bell -->
<span class="tooltips" onclick="myFunctions(event)">
<div class="bell">
<i class='far fa-bell'></i>
</div>
<span id="mypopup" style="display: none;">
<strong>Cape Breton Cares' Brand New Look!</strong>
<br/>
<br/>
We urge you to please share Cape Breton Cares with your friends and family to help provide more meals and support for animal organizations in our local communities.
<p><a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/spread-the-word/" target="_blank">Spread The Word</a></p>
Stay tuned for exciting updates coming soon.
</span>
</span>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Heart -->
<span class="toolstip" onclick="myFunctionss(event)">
<div class="heart">
<i class="far fa-heart"></i>
</div>
<span id="mYpopup" style="display: none;">
Every New Tab you open helps provide meals and support for animal organizations in our local communities. On average we need around 100 New Tabs to provide $1 of support to help our local animal organizations!
</span>
</span>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Menu -->
<span class="toolstips" onclick="myFunctionsss(event)">
<div class="menu">
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<span id="mYpopuP" style="display: none;">
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/contact/" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/donations/" target="_blank">Our Donations</a>
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/privacy-policy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/terms-of-use/" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>
</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

You have multiple `onBodyClick` functions  you write the second one, it replaces the first one, so that's why it's happening. Try to combine all `onBodyClick`  functions .

To hide other popup you can add to your myFunctionsss (inside all this type click functions and change id according to popups you want to hide)

```
var popup = document.getElementById("mYpopuP");
      if (popup.style.display === "none") {
        popup.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("mypopup").style.display="none"; //add something like this
        document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display="none";//add something like this
      } else {
        popup.style.display = "none";
      }
```

Working codepen :https://codepen.io/DarkKelvin/pen/ExKwMev

Comment: The heart works now. Is it possible to make other popups close when another ones opens. Thanks

Comment: You can set style to none for other popups when you are setting block for one popup

Comment: How can I do that. Thanks

Comment: check updated ans i have added code for one pop up mYpopuP when you'll open it it will close all other popups

Comment: Is there a way to close each one as a new one opens, not close all when 1 certain one is clicked. Thanks

Comment: You just add the same code to other functions and change ids accordingly